# How to open an application in Python, and then let the rest of the script run?

Tags: python, subprocess, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to create a script which reloads a web browser called Midori if the internet flickers. But, it seems only to work if I open Midori through the CLI - otherwise, the program crashes after I reload it. I have decided that the best idea is thus to have the script open Midori through the `subprocess` module. So, I put this as one of the first arguments in my code:

```
import subprocess as sub
sub.call(["midori"])
```

The browser opens, but the rest of the program freezes until I quit Midori. I have tried to use threading, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way to open an application through Python, and then let the rest of the script continue to run once said application has been opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

> Run the command described by args. **Wait for command to complete**, then return the returncode attribute.

(Emphasis added)

You can see this is the behaviour we should expect. To get around this, use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) instead. This will not block in the same way:

```
from subprocess import Popen
midori_process = Popen(["midori"])
```

Comment: Sorry that I didn't specify. I am using version 2.7.3

Comment: @xxmbabanexx It shouldn't make a difference, I don't believe the behaviour has changed from 2.x to 3.x. As a tip, you can swap the version using the drop down in the top left of any page of the docs. I use 3.x as much as possible, so I tend to end up on 3.x pages - there is actually very little difference in general.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx the python version isn't what's important here.  It's that you're using the wrong subprocess object.